# Can I totally discard optimus functionality and use the original website driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I use Geforce 630M.

I don't want to use bumblebee, because it is unstable for me.

It will suddenly freeze my ubuntu 12.04 64 bits.

How to do that?

Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

If your BIOS has option to disable optimus functionality **only then you can use the nvidia driver.**

else there is no way you can turnoff intel and work with nvidia because the images generated by the nvidia GPU are transported & displayed through intel card.

You can try with primus. It work with bumblebee but improves performance at large. Because it doesn't use virtualgl (which was intended for remote connection and involves compression etc).

[primus details blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/primus-better-performance-and-less.html)

In conjuction you can use nvidia-experimental driver which is [told](http://nvidianews.nvidia.com/Releases/NVIDIA-Delivers-Massive-Performance-Boost-to-Linux-Gaming-8ac.aspx) to be double the performance for new graphics card.

[How to install guide for bumblebee/primus](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/use-nvidia-experimental-drivers-310.html)

Comment: Is bumblebee/primus can solve the ubuntu freeze of my ubuntu's graphics driver problem? Thank you~

Comment: I have several laptops with optimus and bumblebee all have happened the ubuntu freeze situation.